# Why does git's pre-commit hook verify that HEAD exists?

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit-hook

In its pre-commit hook git seems to verify that HEAD exists. If it doesn't it defaults to a special hash of an empty tree to compare the index to.

```
if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1
then
        against=HEAD
else
        # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
        against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi
```

The hash it defaults to is a special hash. I read that I could also get it via

```
git hash-object -t tree < /dev/null
```

`against` is later used like this

```
# If there are whitespace errors, print the offending file names and fail.
exec git diff-index --check --cached $against --
```

Why does the hook do that? In what situations am I able to do a commit but HEAD would be invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HEAD` always points to the current commit, because:

- it contains the *name* of the current branch (such as `ref: refs/heads/master`), or
- it points directly to the actual commit ID (a "detached HEAD"), so that it contains a raw SHA-1 hash string.

If `HEAD` contains a raw hash value, then `HEAD` is definitely valid, because it has to point to a real commit.  But... what happens in a completely new, empty repository?

You're on branch `master`, so `HEAD` reads `ref: refs/heads/master`.  But what is the tip of branch `master`?  What commit ID is stored in `master` itself?

There are no commits in the repository.  Where will you make `master` point?

Git's solution to this problem is to keep `master` invalid.  That's when `git rev-parse --verify HEAD` fails: `HEAD` says `master`, but `master` does not exist yet.

Internally, Git refers to this as an "unborn branch", or sometimes "orphan branch".  Using `git checkout --orphan newbranch` puts Git into this same state for the newly created (except that it's not really created *yet*) branch `newbranch`.  The `HEAD` reference now contains `ref: refs/heads/newbranch` but there is still no `newbranch` yet.  So every unborn-branch state is like this, but there is one particular one you see every time you create a new, empty repository.